# Can someone explain this O(n) approach

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

So i was doing this question based on Dynamic Programming.
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/ultimate-stairway-to-heaven/description/

Here is the authors solution:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
typedef long long ll;
using namespace std;
#define fastio ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);cout.tie(NULL);
#define repu(v,s,e) for(ll v=s;v<e;v++)
#define repd(v,s,e) for(ll v=s;v>e;v--)
#define mod 1000000007
ll n;
int main(){
    fastio
    cin>>n;
    ll a[n],sum=0,dp[n],temp[n];
    repu(i,0,n) cin>>a[i],temp[i]=0;
    dp[0]=1;
    repu(i,0,n-1){
        temp[i+1]=(temp[i+1]+dp[i])%mod;
        if(i+1+a[i]<n) temp[i+1+a[i]]=(mod+temp[i+1+a[i]]-dp[i])%mod;
        sum=(sum+temp[i+1])%mod;
        dp[i+1]=sum;
    }
    cout<<dp[n-1];
}
```

Can someone please explain this as there was no editorial.
It can also be viewed as no of ways to reach end of array,where each array element gives the no of steps we can take.

Comment: This is code from an online judge/competition site. Such code is almost *always* horrible and bad and should never be used as a learning or teaching resource. All you learn from such sites are bad habits and how to write code for such sites and nothing else useful. Especially, you will not learn anything that would help you get a job doing programming.

Comment: Don't use macros to obscure type names or `for` loops - you're basically forcing anyone who attempts to help you to unpick the macros before they can even have a go.   In any event, the code is not valid C++, since `ll a[n]` where `n` is a variable is not valid C++  (it is part of C99, and supported by some - not all - C++ compilers as a non-standard extension - which doesn't always work too well).

Comment: I understand your concern, but i need to learn how to do this problem in O(n).

Comment: Honestly, looking at crappy or  outright bad code won't help you solve a problem in any way. First of all you need to try it yourself. If it's not efficient enough then measure and profile to find the top two-tree bottlenecks in the program and see if you can optimize those. Also consider common "tricks" of such sites such as figuring out a formula or using [*dynamic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). And ***always*** use good habits and software engineering principles.

Comment: Once you have your own attempt, optimized and using good habits and principles (like semantic names for variables, comments about code and what it does and *why* it does it like that) and you still can't get it to be quite efficient enough, then submit it for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to get help about your program. And doing it yourself will teach you more than just blindly copy some code (bad or not).

Comment: Which parts are you having difficulty understanding?